# Object.defineProperty defines a property that always return undefined value

Tags: html, custom-component

Following along the tutorials that I'm reading from a book, "Learning WebComponents", I'm stuck with one of them, the one that creates a custom element. Find below the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Web Component: custom element example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var objectPrototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

        Object.defineProperty(objectPrototype, 'title', {
            writable : true
        });

        Object.defineProperty(objectPrototype, 'awesomeprop', {
            writable : true
        });

        objectPrototype.createdCallback = function () {
            alert(this.awesomeprop);
        };

        var  myNameElement = document.registerElement("my-name",{
            prototype:objectPrototype
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-name title="Welcome to custom element 1" awesomeprop="hello"></my-name>
    <br>
    <my-name title="Welcome to custom element 2" awesomeprop="hello"></my-name>
</body>
</html>
```

The main issue is that if I follow the code example, the element value will be always undefined.
But, if I do some minor changes, I mean setting a default value, it will work like a charm.

```
Object.defineProperty(objectPrototype, 'title', {
            writable : true,
            value : "myTitle"
        });
```

That makes no sense, because, i would like to use the text that I put into the attribute, that I've also defined.

```
<my-name title="Welcome to custom element 1" awesomeprop="hello"></my-name>
```

I'm guessing that there are some missing steps, or something, but I don´t really know how to go on with this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method is related to the javascript object:

> The Object.defineProperty() method defines a new property directly on an object, or modifies an existing property on an object, and returns the object.

I wrote a short example that shows how you can access the `title` attribute:

```
<my-example title="foo!" aaa="bbb!">bar!</my-example>
<script>
  var Proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
  Object.defineProperty(Proto, 'hallo', {value: 'ween!'});
  Proto.createdCallback = function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('title'));  // -> foo!
    console.log(this.getAttribute('aaa'));    // -> bbb!
    console.log(this.innerHTML);              // -> bar!
  };
  document.registerElement('my-example', { prototype: Proto });

  // Output of the JavaScript object:
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('my-example')[0].hallo); // -> 'ween'
</script>
```

That's the right implementation:

```
var objectPrototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
objectPrototype.createdCallback = function () {
  alert(this.getAttribute('title'));          // <--
  alert(this.getAttribute('awesomeprop'));    // <--
};
var myNameElement = document.registerElement("my-name",{ prototype: objectPrototype });
```

Browser: Google Chrome 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)